# How to remove multiple special characters from a String without any inbuilt functions like replaceAll() for jdk 1.4 below

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, special-characters

Using the below function i am able to simply remove a single special character, need multiple types of them to be removed from a single String.

```
static public String replaceAll(String str, String replace, String replacement )  
{       
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer( str );  
int firstOccurrence = sb.toString().indexOf( replace );  

while( firstOccurrence != -1 )   
{     
sb.replace( firstOccurrence, firstOccurrence + replace.length(), replacement );  
         firstOccurrence = sb.toString().indexOf( replace );  
}  

return sb.toString();   
}
```

Needs this so it works below jdk 1.4 without all the inbuilt function like replaceAll()

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give the example , in which case it's fails to replace all. Actually it's working with simple case

Comment: @Juvanis no problem with using any inbuilt functions below 1.4 as replaAll() is not supported. so thats the case.

Comment: @Krushna OP doesn't mention that he fail with `replaceAll()`. he need to  work this code bellow jdk 1.4.`replaceAll()` start support from JDK 1.4

Comment: @Krushna The case is like having a String with numbers and special characters, all that i need to do is strip off those special char without replaceAll() functions as dev environment is jdk 1.3 and replaceAll() supports 1.4 and above.                            String s= replaceAll("m>sd>da!k",">" , ""); This replaces all > with empty string, but i need to handle to remove ! as well, that does not work ... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is remove all special characters, such as control characters, non-ASCII special characters as well as the ASCII ones like this.

```
public static String stripSpecialCharacters(String str) {
   StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch) || Character.isSpaceChar(ch))
            sb.append(ch);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Note: you want to avoid creating multiple characters or re-arranging characters in a StringBuffer as these become O(N^2) operations in this context.

Comment: this code will replace all special characters..including "space bar" and ruin the sentence.. this is not fit i guess..

Comment: @Abhishek I thought `Character.isSpaceChar(ch)` included the "space bar"  Which method should I have used?

Comment: i didn notice the isSpaceChar()...but not specifically space bar..other characters like full stop exclamation, corpright, this program has a limited scope..

Comment: @PeterLawrey Abhishek is correct - when the string provided is for eg this - `String s= stripSpecialCharacters("90>adb <dask&*()-+ka ndk4839");` with a space, it does not consider space and replace it.

Comment: @Droido I get `90adb daskka ndk4839` on Java 7.  This must be a bug in Java 1.4 as the documentations says `@return true if the character is a space character` You can replace the check with `ch == ' '` if you don't need other white space.

Comment: @PeterLawrey tried this ` if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch) || ch == ' ')sb.append(ch);` it still doesn work :(

Comment: @Droido Can you show me here what you are doing here, because I don't see how that is possible? It works fine here as well http://ideone.com/pRVfHc

Comment: @Droido Are you sure those "spaces" are really spaces and not characters which don't display?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes, peter this is my input `String s= stripSpecialCharacters("90>adb <dask&*()-+ka ndk4839");`

Comment: @Droido and does `Character.isSpaceChar(' ')` return `true`?

Comment: @Droido so if you print out the value of `s` what do you see?

Comment: @PeterLawrey this is the output `90adb daskka ndk4839`

Comment: @PeterLawrey also the method `isLetterOrDigit()` throws out an error for jdk 1.3(not available), i am just able to use `isDigit()`

Answer (score 2):

Edit:   Your question title says that you want to replace multiple characters, , i have used a simple method to replace multiple special characters in "replace" by a specified character..

EDIT:

```
static public String replaceAll(String str, String replace, char replacement )  
{    
String T=""; 
int flag=0;  
for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
{
      char a=str.charAt(i);
      for(int j=0;j<replace.length();j++)
      {
          if(a==replace.charAt(j))
          flag=1;
      }
      if(flag==1)
      {
          T+=replacement;
          flag=0;
      }
      else
          T+=a;
}
return T;   
}
```

this should work in all versions.. i have tested this method with jdk that was available around 8 years ago..

Comment: ur correct, the input is string but the parameter should be of multiple characters, this case is valid for a single char                                             final String specialChars = "[`~!@#$%^&*()_+[\\]\\\\;\',./{}|:\"<>?]"; This might help as a parameter to traverse each char and replace

Comment: okay..so you want to replace all characters in "replace" by a single specific character?

Comment: i mean the replacement should be a string or a single character?

Comment: @Droido So you are happy to keep all the thousands of other special characters?

Comment: String s= replaceAll("m>sd>da!k",">" , ""); This line replaces all the ">" but the case might occur where there are multiple special char in a string for e.g it does not replace "!" with this function but all the ">" in the string.

Comment: @Abhishek Your method works till an extend but does not replace the char with empty, as all that i know to declare a empty char is `char empty = '\0';` or `char empty = '\u0000';` Any idea how to do this?

Comment: @Droido: I just checked it..it does work.. what happens is that empty is declared in the form '\0', but when u add it to a string it vanishes.. it removes the special character and replaces the space by nothing..that's why it isn't visible..

Comment: @Abhishek in that case what is the value of char that you have declared? which takes the third parameter?

Comment: the third parameter can be anything: '\0' or '$' or '~' whatever you want to specify..

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for, assuming you can use the `replaceAll` function you provided:

```
static public String replaceAll(String str, String[] replace, String replacement )  
{        
    String replaced = str;
    for(int i=0; i<replace.length; i++)
    {
        replaced = replaceAll(str, replace[i], replacement);
    } 
    return replaced;
}
```

Edit:
I may have misunderstood your question, I thought you were looking for a way to replace multiple characters with a single method call, in which case you would pass the array of characters you want to replace as the second parameter in this function.

Comment: Yes now you got it right! does this work for multiple char as ur second String array parameter?

Comment: Yes; you will need to pass each character as a separate element in the array.

Comment: Peter Lawrey has a much better answer, I would go with his if all you're going to use this function for is stripping special characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too. But I am not sure lower version than `jdk 1.4` supports with `toCharArray()`

```
 public static String replaceAll(String str, String replace, String replacement )
  {
    char[] strArray =str.toCharArray();
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++){
       if(strArray[i]==replace.toCharArray()[0]){
         sb.append(replacement);
       }else {
           sb.append(strArray[i]);
       }
    }
    return sb.toString();
 }
```

Comment: ` final String specialChars = "[`~!@#$%^&*()_+[\\]\\\\;\',./{}|:\"<>?]";
  String s = replaceAll("90>adb<dask&*()-+kandk4839", specialChars, "");` i checked this on 1.6 and does not seem to strip off the the char - output `90>adb<dask&*()-+kandk4839`

Comment: this works but does not strip off those char. when checked onm 1.6 itself.

Comment: what are those char? + and -?

Comment: none of them are replaced! the comment above shows the output

Comment: You can't do it in one step. you are not getting this correct. method only replace one special char only. you have to try each one by one.

Comment: if this was the case y did i ask the question, the method i provided solves this scenario!